# Introductory preposition

Tags: prepositions

> In making the link between gaming and work, the economists point to compelling data.

Here, why " in making" is said? Why not only " making"?

Comment: It's saying 'while making the link', to connect the two clauses.

Comment: @marcellothearcane The meaning is a little different from "while making the link". In fact, "while making the link" is closer to the meaning *without* "in".

Answer (score 1):

Whether "in" is included in the sentence changes the meaning.

> Making the link between gaming and work, the economists point to compelling data.

Without "in", the sentence means that the economists are making the link *while* they point to the data.

> In making the link between gaming and work, the economists point to compelling data.

When "in" is included, the meaning changes. This sentence means that the economist point to compelling data *by the action of* making the link.

Compare these two sentences:

> In hurrying outside, he made it clear that he was upset.
>
> Hurrying outside, he made it clear that he was upset.

The first sentence means that the man hurried outside *for the purpose of* showing that he was upset. The second sentence just means that he was hurrying outside *while* he made it clear that he was upset, but he must have done something else to actually make it clear, such as making an angry face or saying something unpleasant.

Answer (score 0):

I believe "in making" gives more of an indication that the it is more of a process of possible choices. "In making" sounds somehow wrong or harsh to my ear. "By making" sounds better to my ear. Perhaps someone can let me know if I am right or wrong and also give a serious grammatical answer

Comment: You are partially correct. See my answer for an explanation.